# I want to put Component in TableBody tag

Tags: reactjs

I want to put Table_Row in TableBody tag.

Seeing that 'success' is displayed on the console, it entered the if statement well, and the data is definitely there, but nothing is displayed.

Anyone know how??

In addition, the state is processed asynchronously, so Table_Row is not directly entered, but by designating it as a variable.
If I do that, does the returned value change depending on the state value?

```
const Table_Row = {
        create_Row: (content) => {
            content.map((list) => {
                if (this.state.Board_list_length > 0) {
                    console.log('success');
                    return (
                        <TableRow className="TableRow" key={list.idx} onClick={() => this.handleOpen(list.idx)}>
                            <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">{list.rownum}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className="TableCell" width='20%' align="center">{list.title}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className="TableCell" width='30%' align="center">{list.content}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">{list.writer}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">{this.caculate_date(list.upd_date)}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">{list.hit}</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    );
                }
                else { //웨 안돼
                    return (
                        <TableRow hover className="TableRow" key="0">
                            <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">adssd</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className="TableCell" width='20%' align="center">das</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className="TableCell" width='30%' align="center">adsd</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">ads</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">asdsd</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">asd</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    );
                }
            })
        }
    }


return(

           <div className="Table_div">
                <Paper className="Paper">
                    <Table className="Table" >
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">번호</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className="TableCell" width='20%' align="center">제목</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className="TableCell" width='30%' align="center">내용</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">작성자</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">작성일</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">조회수</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>

                        <TableBody>
                        {
                            Table_Row.create_Row(
                                (this.state.Board_rows_per_page > 0
                                    ? this.state.Board_List.slice(this.state.Board_page * this.state.Board_rows_per_page, this.state.Board_page * this.state.Board_rows_per_page + this.state.Board_rows_per_page)
                                    : this.state.Board_List
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        </TableBody>
                        <TableFooter className="TableFooter">
                            <TableRow>
                                <TablePagination className="TablePagination"
                                    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, { label: 'All', value: -1}]}
                                    colSpan={5}
                                    count={this.state.Board_list_length}
                                    rowsPerPage={this.state.Board_rows_per_page}
                                    page={this.state.Board_page}
                                    SelectProps={{
                                        inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'rows per page' },
                                        native: true,
                                    }}
                                    onPageChange={this.handleChangePage}
                                    onRowsPerPageChange={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                                    ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActions}
                                />
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableFooter>
                    </Table>
                </Paper>
            </div>

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return your map, `return content.map((list) => { ... };`

Another option is to force a return with the following syntax:

```js
const Table_Row = {
  create_Row: (content) => content.map((list) => { ... })
}
```